# Looking for a single phrase, word or even proverb for "always being condemned for whatever someone does"

Tags: word-requests

Consider the situation in which an employer dislikes one of his employees.
The employee is always condemned by the employer for whatever the employee does.
In other words, even though the employee does a good result, he is still condemned.

Is there a single phrase, word, or even proverb for "always being condemned" in Japanese?

I want to convert the following

> 僕は何をしても、いつも非難される。

to

> 僕は「the phrase in question」です。

or

> 僕は「the phrase in question] になる/する/させる/される。

or something like these. Proverb is also welcome!

Note: It is not necessarily the relation between employer and the employee.

Comment: First, 「何でもしても」 makes no sense.   Seems you would have wanted to say 「何をしても」.  Second, are you sure you want your "new" sentence to end in a 「です」?  Unless you are looking for a NOUN, it might not be easy to end it with 「です」.   I am asking because you clearly said you wanted "a phrase", not "a word" or "a noun".

Comment: 何がっても私にせいになっている

Comment: ^ oldergod, You meant to say 「何が**あ**っても私**の**せいになる」 (Whatever happens, it's my fault / they blame me)？ I'd say 「何をしても文句を言われる」or「何をやっても怒られる」, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd normally say...

「僕は、何を｛しても/やっても｝（いつも）｛文句を言われる/ケチをつけられる/怒られる/叱られる/責められる｝。」

I don't think we have a single phrase, set phrase or proverb to say this, I'm afraid...

(Maybe 「僕は（～～に）[目]{め}の[敵]{かたき}にされている」?)

Answer (score 1):

My choice would be

> "僕は「雇｛やと｝い主｛ぬし｝」or「上司｛じょうし｝」の**嫌｛きら｝われ者｛もの｝です**。”

Translated,

> I am an employee always shunned by my employer / boss.

Have a good day.

Comment: Note that, although this fits in the context, 嫌われ者 means those disliked in general. A 嫌われ者 doesn't necessarily be blamed for everything; one may be just ignored, spoken ill of, etc.